# How can we filter product options in salesforce cpq?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

How can I filter product option while creating a quote in salesforce cpq.

Example I have a main product "Dell Laptop" - I create 2 features "Hardware" and "Software". I have a "region" field in product option with values X or Y

I add below product options in relevant feature and region
Hardware - CPU,RAM etc (no region)
Software - 
X region: MS Office, Notepad
Y region: Firefox

Now when I create a quote. I should be able to select add options and in software feature I need a filter value based on which only the RELEVANT PRODUCT OPTIONS will load
So I select X region only MSOffice and Notepad should load.

How can I solve this problem?

I have tried looking in lookup query and lookup data. The problem is I may have  15-20 options in one feature and adding lookup data with show and hide for two feature will increase manual work and creating combination for each feature

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps:

1. Create a Configuration Attribute.
2. Add them to the Feature.
3. Create a Product Rule Selection Type.
4. Associate this Product Rule with Bundle.

For more detail click here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrlef7SIYLIS7FKdtPBqDUw?view_as=subscriber